# How to track when rows have been published from Google BigQuery to Pub/Sub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, database-migration, google-cloud-pubsub

I am writing data from google bigquery (googles SQL datawarehouse) to mysql using a cron job. We used google pub/sub as an intermediary (read from bigquery, publish to pub/sub then subscribe from pub/sub and write to mysql(on cloudsql)). We put a published_flag boolean on each row of the bigquery table to signify when a row has been successfully published. The problem with this is that bigquery has a limited number of UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statements per day per table. Also, we are working with billions of rows. What is an alternative solution to this problem? Are there any GCP services or web services that can more elegantly handle this problem?

the options for us are currently:

1. buy more bigQuery quota (not scalable)
2. write directly to mysql from bigquery (not robust and decoupled)
3. have another table in another service like google data store that keeps track of the published rows ( doesn't seem elegant and adds complexity).
4. Update the publish flag in bulk (also not scalable)

Comment: As for the DML limit, I don't think there's anything you can do about this. BigQuery really isn't designed for DML, hence the hard limits. However, why are you moving so much data out of BigQuery to MySQL in the first place? It sounds odd. It's usually the other way around!

Comment: @GrahamPolley Good question, we are aggregating and compressing the data from BiQuery before writing to MySql. The front end can then make faster and cheaper queries when querying from MySql. Also I know that using DML to update the table is not a good solution and was looking for a completely different solution.

Comment: How is your workflow? I think Cloud Dataflow is the most appropriate cloud product for this case.

Comment: @enlelin I think you maybe right, Cloud Dataflow maybe a more legitimate way of moving data from BigQuery to PubSub. I'm assuming that Dataflow has a way of tracking which rows have already been published so they are not published again?

Comment: I could say you don't have to use Pub/Sub in this case.You can use [BigqueryIO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io#reading-from-bigquery) to read from Bigquery and [JdbcIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html) to write it into SQL database. If you are worried about duplicated data, see [Exactly-once processing in Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/07/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-cloud-dataflow-part-3-sources-and-sinks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining cronjob and `Pub/SUb` is probably not a good choice for this use case. The most appropriate product for this should be [`Cloud Dataflow`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) since it is designed for ETL. In this specific case, you can use [BigqueryIO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io#reading-from-bigquery) to read from `Bigquery` and [JdbcIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html) to write it into SQL database.